# Getting 2 defectives

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution

An item is produced by a machine in large numbers. The machine is known to produce
5% defectives. A quality control engineer is testing the items randomly. What is the
probability that at least 5 items are examined in order to get 2 defectives? 
[image]

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wnat you describe is a negative binomial (2,.05) distribution. The pmf is 
$$f(k)=P(X=k)={(k+r-1) \choose k} (p)^r(1-p)^k$$, where $r=2$ and $p=0.05$ for the given distribution. Then
$$P(X \geq z) = 1- P(X < z) = 1- P(X \leq z-1)  = 1- \sum_{k=2}^{z-1} f(k) = 1- \sum_{k=2}^{z-1} {(k+1) \choose k}(.05)^2(.95)^k.$$

For $z=5$, we get 
$$P(X \geq 5)= 1- \sum_{k=2}^{4} {(k+1) \choose k}(.05)^2(.95)^k.$$

......